# Is there a way to change a short name in OS X

Tags: macos, user-account

I am trying change the Short Name for an account on my computer. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these steps to change the short username of an account on your computer:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Choose the "Users & Groups" preference pane
3. If the padlock at the bottom left is locked, click on it to unlock it with an administrator password
4. Control-click on the account in the users list
5. A menu will appear with "Advanced Options…". Select that and you will get a sheet where you can change the account name.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good knowledge base article, [HT1428](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1428?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), on how to change the short name of an account.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.